# How do I reorder vertices in a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a directed acyclic graph $g$, and I'd like to re-order the vertices in this graph object such that when I call

```
VertexList[myGraph]
```

the vertices appear in topologically sorted order. The naive solution is to make a new graph as follows:

```
myGraph = Graph[TopologicalSort[g], EdgeList[g]]
```

but it seems that the graph object sorts its vertices. So this method is no good.

Comment: Right! Thank you.

Comment: So I still don't understand the question... The two graphs are exactly the same, except that the second has the vertices in a different order and the layout is different. Did you want the vertex order to be different but the layout to be the same?

Comment: I'm not concerned about the layout. I'd like only for the second graph to have vertices in topologically sorted order. My DAG has one source and one sink, so I would want VertexList[g][[1]] to be the source of g and VertexList[g][[-1]] to be the sink. Do you have suggestions for how I might change the question to make this more clear?

Comment: But that indeed is the case... With your code above, compare `TopologicalSort[g]` and `VertexList[myGraph]`. They're the same. The first element is the source and the last is the sink. I think you've just been looking at the values for the wrong graph.

Comment: I would recommend never to rely on `VertexList` or `EdgeList` having a specific order.  You can always create your own edge/vertex list with any order you like.  What kind of application do you need this for?

Answer (score 4):

At least in v9 if you provide an explicit vertex list for `Graph`, it maintains that order of the vertices (unless you add/remove vertices or edges via e.g. `VertexAdd` or `EdgeAdd`). So your suggested method should work, with an **extra caveat**! A DAG might have multiple equivalent topological orders, which are not identical. Consider for example (thanks to MichaelE2 for pointing it out):

```
SeedRandom@3;
g = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph@{10, 15}, "Acyclic"]
g2 = Graph[TopologicalSort@g, EdgeList@g];
TopologicalSort@g
TopologicalSort@g2
```

> ```
> {3, 1, 2, 4, 10, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6}
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6}
> ```

Both sortings are correct. Unfortunately, since we don't know how vertices are sorted inside `Graph`, we cannot rely on that specifying a topologically sorted vertex list will result in the same order of vertices when queried by `VertexList` (the original problem):

```
 VertexList@g2 === TopologicalSort@g2   (* ==> False *)
```

This is because `g2` lists vertices in the topological order returned by `g` which is not identical to the topological order returned by `g2`. I assume that the actual vertex ordering in `Graph` is based on the order of supplied vertices **and** edges.

### Quick and dirty solution

The solution is to feed the vertex order that is returned by `TopologicalSort` *for a second time*. I've tested it for 10000 different random seeds, it seems consistent.

```
SeedRandom@1;
g = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph@{10, 15}, "Acyclic"];
g2 = Graph[TopologicalSort@Graph[TopologicalSort@g, EdgeList@g], EdgeList@g];
VertexList@g2 === TopologicalSort@g2       (* ==> True  *)
```

With the addition, that the layout is not preserved:

```
{g, g2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can try to supply the appropriate vertex coordinates and layout method, just to realize that the edge tolerance cannot be transferred:

```
coord = Thread[VertexList@g -> (VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates])];
g3 = Graph[TopologicalSort@g, EdgeList@g, 
         GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
         VertexCoordinates -> (TopologicalSort@g /. coord)];

VertexList@g3 === TopologicalSort@g3   (* ==> True *)

g3
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have no idea how to preserve the edge function.

Comment: Starting with `SeedRandom@3`, `VertexList@g2 === TopologicalSort@g2` returns `False` for me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 God, this is annoying! Let me figure out if there is a solution before I delete it.

Comment: I don't think that a topological sort is unique.  I think that's the issue.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I arrived to the same conclusion. Please see edit. The problem is that one cannot be sure that this will hold for all graphs and/or all future *Mathematica* version...

Comment: `TopologicalSort@g` seems to depend on the form/order of the edges (only) in `g`.  I expect this dependency will be stable - I suspect the algorithm is fairly simple and can't be improved. So as long as you use `EdgeList@g` each time, the t-sort should give the same order.  `RandomGraph` stores the edges in a `SparseArray` object, but `Graph[v, List[..]]` stores the edges as a list of pairs of positions of the vertices in `v`.  That's why the first t-sort you do changes things, but subsequent t-sorts are stable.  HTH -- comments have to be short :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my humble contribution to that issue. Although it only works for "one way" edges but at least it works in v8.

```
myEdgeList[g_] := Module[{mat, edges},
  mat = UpperTriangularize@(List @@@ AdjacencyMatrix@g);
  edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ SortBy[Position[mat, 1], Last]]
```

With `GridGraph`:

```
coor[g_] := (PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList[g])

g = GridGraph[{3, 3}];
GraphicsRow[Graph[#, VertexCoordinates -> coor@g, PlotLabel -> #2,
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]& 
  @@@ {{EdgeList@g,"EdgeList"}, {myEdgeList@g, "myEdgeList"}},ImageSize->450]
```

[image: EdgeList issue with GridGraph]

With `RandomGraph`:

```
SeedRandom@1;
g = RandomGraph[{10, 15}, PlotLabel -> "Raw Graph"];
GraphicsRow[{g, Graph[EdgeList@g, PlotLabel -> "EdgeList"], 
  Graph[myEdgeList@g, PlotLabel -> "myEdgeList"]}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: EdgeList issue with RandomGraph]

It's working very well with `GridGraph` and it's inversing the `RandomGraph` in this case. 
Even if it's far to work for every kind of `Graph` it might help for some.